# File changes disappear when I stage them in git

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I am working on a C# project in Visual Studio that is stored in a git repo. The .gitignore is missing some entries, and there are a couple files that are generated in the Visual Studio build process which aren't ignored and have been committed to the repo. The files contain our software's version numbers, and are used to get the version info into the built executable.

Whenever we build the project, the files are regenerated, but usually the contents of the files don't change at all (because the version number hasn't been updated). However, the files still show up as having changed. If I run a `git diff`, only one of the files shows up, and the + and - lines are identical. Even weirder: if I run `git add .`, only that file shows up as staged. The other one disappears.

Here's the outputs of git status and git add

[image: Outputs of git add and git status]

Here's the output of git diff

[image: Output of git diff]

**My question is:** **How is this possible?** It completely goes against my mental model of how git works. The files have identical names and contents, so they shouldn't show up as having changed. If a file that is "changed" is staged, how does it disappear from the index? How is it that the two files get treated differently?

To be clear: I'm not asking how to fix this situation. I'm pretty sure I know how to do that, but the details will involve details specific to the project. I'm just asking how this is possible in the first place.

Comment: Check them before/after with an hex editor.... There must be a difference

Comment: You're right. The problem was newline characters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77463149/1744576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from the log messages, it might just be some "issue" with whitespace or control characters. As eftshift0 mentioned in the comments, I'd look into it with something more detailed than just the terminal output.

Comment: That could explain what's going on with the version.xml file, since that at least shows up in ```git diff```. But I don't think that could explain what's going on in the AssemblyVersion.cs file and why it disappears from the index when staged. 

Still worth a shot though. I'll take a look.

Comment: You were right. Turns out they were both caused by non-printing characters. I wrote out a full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77463149/1744576

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out (mostly). eftshift() and JanS had a spot-on suggestion: I had to look at the files in a hex-editor. It's all about line endings.

The version.xml file was easy: the committed version has no newline characters. The newly-generated version does. You can actually see that in the diff picture I posted ("No newline at end of file" only for the - line). I'm not sure *how* that happens since they were both generated from the same script, but that's a question for me to figure out on my own.

The C#/AssemblyVersion.cs file is more interesting. The project is a C# Windows app and uses msbuild build scripts, which, naturally, generate windows-style line-endings (CR+LF). However, for some reason-- even though it's a Windows app and the whole project infrastructure relies on MS products-- the git repo is configured to convert everything to Unix-style line endings (LF).

So the committed AssemblyVersion.cs file has Unix-style endings. The newly-generated file is *almost* identical, but it has Windows-style endings. That means the file is different and shows up as changed in `git status`. But then when you run `git add` on the generated file, it converts the line endings (it does this in-memory when you run `git diff` too, which you can also see in my other screenshot). With the line endings converted, the working set file is 100% identical to the committed version, so it is no longer changed and therefore there's nothing to stage.

(I use zsh in WSL for all my command-line work, but I confirmed the behavior is the same when using git through Powershell)